# AGP 7.2 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_3570298/Offline; for instrumentation tests

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jacoco

When running android instrumentation tests with AGP 7.2 (android studio chipmunk) I am seeing the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_b6258fc/Offline;
   at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:13)
   at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_b6258fc.Offline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.abc.appname.develop.test-VAV8qDGNBpOvARX_Y9h_SA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.abc.appname.develop.test-VAV8qDGNBpOvARX_Y9h_SA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
   at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:13) 
   at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0) 
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
```

I have jacoco 0.8.8 setup as well, but when I turn `debug.testCoverageEnabled` to false, the instrumentation tests pass successfully.

Using jacoco 0.8.7 has the same issue, but both 0.8.7 and 0.8.8 work correctly on AGP 7.1.3 (bumblebee).

Comment: Do you want to report this on google issue tracker?

Comment: Found this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222338458. The current suggestion is to skip 7.2 unless more people complain.